# Openshift tail asks me to relogin

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to tail my application in openshift but it asks me to login. But I am already logged in. I do

```
rhc account -l <email>
#adding password
Login <email> on openshift.redhat.com
-----------------------------------------------
ID:                 <id>
Plan:               Free
Gears Used:         2
Gears Allowed:      3
Domains Allowed:    1
Allowed Gear Sizes: small
SSL Certificates:   no
```

But when I try to tail my app it asks me to relogin

```
rhc tail beta
Please sign in to start a new session to openshift.redhat.com.
Password:
```

Do I nedd to add anything else? Is it better to run `rhc setup` instead of `account -l`?

EDIT: I had to use

```
rhc setup -l <email>
```

but `-l` flag is not stated in the help of setup command when you use

```
rhc help setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the rhc logout command, then just run rhc setup without the -l and see if that helps.  otherwise you can try deleting your ~/.openshift directory and then running rhc setup again and let the file be re-created for you. It should ask if you want to create an authorization key so you don't have to keep entering your password.

Comment: Just using rhc setup without the -l logged me to my other openshift account. So the -l <email> flag was important. Didn't try deleting the ~/.openshift deleting cause it worked with the -l flag

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that rhc can keep authorizations for multiple logins.